# postgres insert into table with many partitions (values clause)

Tags: postgresql

I am aware that having many (e.g. 10.000) partitions on a table can be a problem in postgres, as it can happen that the execution plan contains all 10.000 partitions when **SELECT**ing. Here is an example with 4 partitions and a potential way to circumvent the problem by directly selecting from the table of a partition. Because of generic plans this can happen even when only one partition is accessed.

```
CREATE TABLE tst_tt (
    c1 int4 NOT NULL,
    c2 text NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST (c1);

CREATE TABLE tst_tt_1 PARTITION OF tst_tt  FOR VALUES IN (1);
CREATE TABLE tst_tt_2 PARTITION OF tst_tt  FOR VALUES IN (2);
CREATE TABLE tst_tt_3 PARTITION OF tst_tt  FOR VALUES IN (3);
CREATE TABLE tst_tt_default PARTITION OF tst_tt DEFAULT;

explain select * from tst_tt;

QUERY PLAN                                                                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Append  (cost=0.00..116.20 rows=5080 width=36)                                  |
  ->  Seq Scan on tst_tt_1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)               |
  ->  Seq Scan on tst_tt_2  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)               |
  ->  Seq Scan on tst_tt_3  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)               |
  ->  Seq Scan on tst_tt_default tst_tt_4  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)|
  
explain select * from tst_tt_1;

QUERY PLAN                                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------+
Seq Scan on tst_tt_1  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)|

prepare plan_a as select * from tst_tt where c1 = $1;

explain execute plan_a(3);
QUERY PLAN                                                     |
---------------------------------------------------------------+
Seq Scan on tst_tt_3 tst_tt  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)|
  Filter: (c1 = 3)                                             |

set plan_cache_mode='force_generic_plan';
explain execute plan_a(3);
QUERY PLAN                                                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
Append  (cost=0.00..103.62 rows=24 width=36)                           |
  Subplans Removed: 3                                                  |
  ->  Seq Scan on tst_tt_3 tst_tt_1  (cost=0.00..25.88 rows=6 width=36)|
        Filter: (c1 = $1)                                              |
```

My question now is about **INSERT**ing with a **VALUES** clause. Can this ever cause the plan to consider all 10.000 partitions when e.g. 10 rows are inserted? In my testing it seems INSERT with VALUES clause is immune to that problem. It seems to magically just do it without creating a plan with all 10.000 partitions?

```
explain insert into tst_tt values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(999,'default');

QUERY PLAN                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
Insert on tst_tt  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=0 width=0)                |
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=36)|
  
explain insert into tst_tt_1 values (1,'a'),(1,'a');

QUERY PLAN                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
Insert on tst_tt_1  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=0 width=0)              |
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=36)|
  
prepare plan as insert into tst_tt values ($1,'a'),($2,'b'),($3,'default');

explain execute plan(1,2,999);

QUERY PLAN                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
Insert on tst_tt  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=0 width=0)                |
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=36)|

set plan_cache_mode='force_generic_plan';
explain execute plan(1,2,999);

QUERY PLAN                                                        |
------------------------------------------------------------------+
Insert on tst_tt  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=0 width=0)                |
  ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=36)|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `INSERT` on a partitioned table still has to do extra work to determine which partition will receive the new row. So an `INSERT` to a table with many partitions will be slower than an `INSERT` to a table with few partitions. You can measure the difference, but you don't see it reflected in `EXPLAIN`.